# Wrap node in new parent node?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xpath, transformation

I'm using an XSLT stylesheet to transform CSV to XML, but I also need to transform the XML with a few templates after the CSV transform. Below is part of the stylesheet that is supposed to wrap any `<UPC>031878025147</UPC>` nodes as:

`<UPCs>
    <UPC>031878025147</UPC>
<UPCs>`

Here's the snippet of the stylesheet that's supposed to wrap the `<UPC>` nodes with `<UPCs>`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fn="fn" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//UPC[preceding-sibling::ExternalId]">
      <xsl:variable select="." name="curElem" />
      <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <UPCs>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$curElem" />
        </UPCs>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a snippet of XML that it would be parsing:

```
<Feed name="example" incremental="false" extractDate="2016-04-28T13:42:09-05:00" xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.5">
  <Brands>
    <Brand removed="false">
      <ExternalId>brands</ExternalId>
      <Name>Brands</Name>
      <!--BrandPageUrl>http://www.kolcraft.com/brands.html</BrandPageUrl-->
    </Brand>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Brands>
  <Categories>
    <Category removed="false">
      <ExternalId>baby-products</ExternalId>
      <Name>Baby Products</Name>
      <CategoryPageUrl>http://www.kolcraft.com/baby-products.html</CategoryPageUrl>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>ED003-QCX</ExternalId>
      <UPC>031878025147</UPC>
      <Name>Sealy Naturals-Cotton Crib Mattress Pad</Name>
      <Description>Give baby plush comfort from natural cotton fibers with the innovative Sealy Naturals-Cotton Crib Mattress Pad.</Description>
      <ProductPageUrl>http://www.kolcraft.com/sealy-naturals-cotton-crib-mattress-pad.html</ProductPageUrl>
      <ImageUrl>http://www.kolcraft.com/media/catalog/product/e/d/ed003-qcx-1_1_4.jpg</ImageUrl>
      <CategoryExternalId>crib-bedding</CategoryExternalId>
    </Product>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Products>
</Feed>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be catching any `<UPC>` nodes that are outside of a parent `<UPCs>` node. What am I missing here? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the xml you are supposed to be processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a default namespace declaration in your XML

```
<Feed ... xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.5">
```

This means the `Feed` element and all descendant elements are in that namespace. However, your XSLT is not taking into this namespace, and so that is looking to match an element `UPC` which is in no namespace, which is not the same thing.

As you are using XSLT 2.0 you can actually make use of the `xpath-default-namespace` to specify a default namespace for xpath expressions like your template match. You would also need to define a default namespace for your XSLT too to ensure the new `UPCs` gets output in the same namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fn="fn" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.5"
  xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.5"
  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UPC[preceding-sibling::ExternalId]">
        <UPCs>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </UPCs>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have also simplified the template, as I couldn't see a new for the variable to the for-each statements.

EDIT: In response to comment, note that it is not necessary to use a double-slash `//` at the start of a template match.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The double-slash is un-necessary in this instance, so I have removed it. Thanks!